# Selenium opens new unwanted browser windows from imported files of python project

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating a webscraper to collect prices on a few items overtime on a merchant website.
I have set up the project in pycharm with different files for the different functions that will be repeated often. But every time I try to use the imported function to navigate a new window is opened at the google homepage URL.

code from file main.py:

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, use_subprocess=True)
driver.get(URL)

print(__name__)
from navigate_home_page import go_home
go_home()


time.sleep(50)
```

code from file navigate_home_page:

```
# this file will simply navigate back to the walmart home page
# for use when errors occur
URL = "https://www.walmart.com/account/login"
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
# this line helps us look for elements
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
s = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
#global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, use_subprocess=True)



def go_home():
    print(__name__)
    xp_homepage = "//i[contains(@class, 'ld ld-Spark')]"
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xp_homepage)))
    finally:
        element.click()



if __name__ == '__main__':
  driver.get(URL)
  URL = "https://www.walmart.com/account/login"
  time.sleep(30)
  print('hurry up')
  time.sleep(5)
  xp_homepage = "//i[contains(@class, 'ld ld-Spark')]"
  #"//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Walmart Homepage')]" wanted to use this but its not intractable
  xp_homepage_link_id ="//a[contains(@link-identifier, 'Desktop')]"
  home_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xp_homepage)
  home_button.click()
  print('it worked!')
  time.sleep(4)
  print( 'this was run on navigate_home_page as a test')
```

It is set up this way so that I may reuse navigation code over and over again, as well as individually test sections if there are site updates and/or errors. The navigate_home_page has its example test under "if **name** == '**main**':", this does require you to have a login to function (I do this manually).

The result is a login page that I need to login to, and also just a blank unwated google home page.

My question: How do I avoid instantiating a new browser when trying to use a navigation function imported from another file and in this way using the imported function on the window opened in the previous lines of code?
Secondary for clarification: Is it possible or will I have to write one long, one file navigation, full of repeating code while using selenium?

Comment: understood. `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, use_subprocess=True)` this is global, that's the issue.

Comment: @Jiya Unfortunally I have to leave that in there it is what makes the imports compatible with my browser. DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

Comment: what he ment was that the driver is defined as global in main.py

Comment: ahh yes, well I removed that and it still happens. I am attempting to put things into classes as a form of organization, in the hopes that it will not instantiate multiple browsers...I am not sure if a class method can inherit an already open browser. I'm going to update the above to remove the global call.